# Ads and application automatically showing up on home screen or as a message indicator

Tags: ads

Why do programs like badoo or random games and applications pop up ever now and then on my home screen?

Why is it that some times my green indicator light shows me a green plus sign for some add?

Did I inadvertintly agree for this?

How can I stop it permanetly?

Answer (score 0):

what homescreen?  iPhone, Android, PC, browser, a specific web site?